# Не стоит ли показывать больше информации о новом участнике?

Tags: предложение, знаки, индикатор-новичка

Есть весьма полезный знак "[Информированный](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/84/informed)", сигнализирующий, что новый участник не поленился потратить минуту на чтение информации об основных принципах  ресурса. Но, к сожалению, убедиться в наличии этого знака можно только после перехода в профиль пользователя. Может быть нам стоит, кроме индикатора "Новый участник", показывать ещё и индикатор о том, что новый участник относится серьёзно к ресурсу и уважительно к сообществу?

Answer (score 5):

Нет, не стоит.

Индикатор того, что новый участник относится серьёзно к ресурсу и уважительно к сообществу - это **грамотно сформулированные вопросы и/или ответы**.

Наличие знака у участника говорит лишь о том, что он пролистал справку, а не о том, прочитал он ее и/или усвоил. Настоящим же индикатором прочтения(!), будет являться следование(!) букве прочтенного материала.

---

А вот что было бы интересным, так это подобный знак предназначенный для глаз новичков. Т.е. некий геймифицированный индикатор о том, что им стоит изучить справку. Такой, чтобы его нельзя было просто так обдурить нажав несколько раз PageDown на одной странице. Настоящая "ачивка".

Comment: Да, просмотр вводной не гарантия следования правилам, но положительный сигнал.

Comment: Гораздо больший вводный сигнал - это, например, отсутствие грамматических и синтаксических ошибок  (т.е. то что участник достаточно образован или хотя бы прочитал набранный текст перед отправкой)

Comment: А ещё лучше чтобы новичок нагуглил решение своей проблемы самостоятельно и не задал вопрос :)

Answer (score 3):

Формулировка мне совершенно не нравится, но сама идея добавить индикатор - вроде хорошая. По нему можно будет понимать, насколько детально стоит писать свои комментарии, относящиеся к форматированию и тематике.

Answer (score 2):

Если суть предложения в том, что добавить знак для "новых участников, которые относится серьёзно к ресурсу и уважительно к сообществу", то само предложение становиться неудачным по ряду причин озвученных ниже.

1. **Само предложение крайне размыто и противоречиво.** А что значит "серьёзно и уважительно"? Тем более для нового участника. Какие критерии вы предлагаете? Противоречие также в том, что "новый участник" и "серьёзное отношение" звучит довольно противоречиво. Это то же самое что для пары на первом свидании пытаться определить серьёзность отношений. Пока же ничего не ясно. На данный момент "новым" участник [считается в течение недели после первого поста](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314287/346987), как здесь определить "серьёзность"?
2. **Для тех, у кого метки не будет, могут посчитать это оскорбительным**. А если у кого-то не будет метки? То это значит он относиться к ресурсу несерьёзно и неуважительно? Я думаю, что мы не должны демонстрировать такое отношение, тем более к новичкам. Насчёт "уважительности", то она должна подразумеваться по умолчанию. Раз участник зарегистрирован и хоть как-то активен, то значит ресурс что-то значит для него.
3. **Отношение — это то, что меняется со временем.** Участник может какое-то время относится "серьёзно и уважительно", а затем перестать. Как это решить и в чём смысл значка тогда? Или он должен быть с участником пока он по каким-то критериям "относится серьёзно и уважительно"?
4. **Данный вопрос следует рассматривать на [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com).** Мы не сможем создать локально какой-то значок. Даже если вас поддержат куча человек. Поэтому вам следует попытать счастья на главной мете. Но даже поддержка широких народных масс на MSE — не гарантия внедрения значка, но сильно повышает шансы реализации.  Но шансы этой реализации довольно малы, особенно в случае значков. Последнее реализованное предложение было аж в далёком 2012.

Comment: Неготовность участника потратить одну минуту на ознакомление со справкой  - это форма сознательного отрицания правил сообщества. Что в свою очередь признак неуважения.

Comment: По поводу второго пункта: Решительно не понимаю, как из регистрации и активности следует уважительность. Я каждый день вижу вопросы от людей, которые пришли не просить, но требовать помощи, притом иногда в хамской манере. Им плевать на ресурс, других его участников и правила.

Comment: По поводу третьего пункта: Я предлагаю показывать индикатор "ознакомленности" со справкой до тех пор, пока показывается индикатор нового участника.